# Defining lambda addition without using the successor function

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, lambda-calculus

I am familiar with defining the `ADD` function on top of the `SUCC` function, such as in the following:

```js
const ONE = f => a => f(a);   
const SUCC = n => f => a => f(n(f)(a));        // SUCC = λnfa.f(nfa)
const ADD = n1 => n2 => n1(SUCC)(n2);          // ADD  = λnk.n SUCC k 
console.log(ADD(ONE)(ONE)(x => x+1)(0));
// 2
```

However, how would I define add if there wasn't a successor function already defined? I tried using substitution to get the following, but I'm not sure why it's not working. What do I have screwed up here?

```js
const ONE = f => a => f(a);
const ADD = n1 => n2 => f => a => n1(f(n1(f)(a)))(n2);
console.log(ADD(ONE)(ONE)(x => x+1)(0));
// TypeError: f is not a function
```

Comment: `const ADD = n1 => n2 => n1(n => f => a => f(n(f)(a)))(n2)`? (can be eta reduced to `const ADD = n1 => n1(n => f => a => f(n(f)(a)))`)

Comment: [cs.se] would probably be a better place for lambda calculus questions. Translating them into JS doesn't really change the nature of the question much.

Comment: @cherryblossom I see, man that gets pretty abstract so quickly. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @cherryblossom so does the lambda expression become `ADD = λnk.n ( λnfa.f(nfa) ) k` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const ADD = n1 => n2 => n1(n => f => a => f(n(f)(a)))(n2)
// ADD = λnk.n (λnfa.f (n f a)) k
```

This can also be eta-reduced to

```js
const ADD = n1 => n1(n => f => a => f(n(f)(a)))
// ADD = λn.n (λnfa.f (n f a))
```

When doing substitution, you simply replace the term to be substituted with its definition:

- `n1 => n2 => n1(SUCC)(n2)`
- definition of `SUCC`: `n => f => a => f(n(f)(a))`
- replace `SUCC` with the above definition: `n1 => n2 => n1(n => f => a => f(n(f)(a)))(n2)`

---

Another way you could define `ADD` is like this:

```js
const ADD = m => n => f => x => m(f)(n(f)(x))
// ADD = λmnfx.m f (n f x)
```

The Church numerals `m` and `n` can be seen as functions that take a function `f` and produce another function that applies `f` a particular number of times. In other words, `n(f)` can be seen as ‘repeat `f` `n` times’.

Therefore, `ADD(m)(n)` should return a function that repeats a function `m + n` times.

```js
const ADD =
  m => // first number
  n => // second number
  f => // function to be repeated
  x => // value
  (
    m(f) // 2. then apply f m times
    (n(f)(x)) // 1. apply f n times
  )
```

`ADD(ONE)` is also equivalent to `SUCC` (as you would expect):

- `ADD(ONE)`
- `(m => n => f => x => m(f)(n(f)(x)))(ONE)` (definition of `ADD`)
- `n => f => x => ONE(f)(n(f)(x))` (beta-reduction)
- `n => f => x => (f => a => f(a))(f)(n(f)(x))` (definition of `ONE`)
- `n => f => x => (a => f(a))(n(f)(x))` (beta-reduction)
- `n => f => x => f(n(f)(x))` (beta-reduction)
- `SUCC` (definition of `SUCC`)

For more information, see [‘Church encoding’ on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding#Church_numerals).

Comment: thanks so much for taking the time here. Could you explain a bit about how you got to the second definition of add?

Comment: I see how you can move this part over -- https://gyazo.com/d1bbc8a55441ce19e0b418a26e18d8e1 -- but why does it then become `n1(f)(...)` and not `n1(f(...))` ? Would you want to show how that beta reduction works?

Comment: @David542 I’m not sure how to reduce the first definition of `ADD` into the second one, but I’ve added some explanation to my answer for how the second one is derived.